The number of direct sum of elementary abelian 2-groups
Let $G=(Z_2)^n$, I want to know the number of direct sum of $G$($G=H \oplus K$) or a fine upper bound.
For $G=Z_2 \oplus Z_2$, I have calculated that all of its direct sum decomposition is as follows:
$$G = \left\{ a \right\} \oplus \left\{ {a,b,c,d} \right\} = \left\{ {a,b} \right\} \oplus \left\{ {a,c} \right\} = \left\{ {a,b} \right\} \oplus \left\{ {a,d} \right\} = \left\{ {a,c} \right\} \oplus \left\{ {a,d} \right\}$$
where $a=(0,0),b=(0,1),c=(1,0),d=(1,1)$

You could write a programme in GAP for this sort of thing.

Not for all $n$, of course, but enough to see a pattern, hopefully.

In this answer I will make use of the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space structure of this group and as such denote it as $V=\mathbb{F}_2^n$.
As a first observation, we note that the number of direct sum compositions like this is exactly half the number of projections on $V$, that is, endomorphisms $P\in \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ that satisfy $P^2=P$. To see this, observe that any projection $P$ gives rise to the decomposition $\ker P\oplus \mathrm{im}P$ (and $1-P$ gives the same decomposition), while any direct sum decomposition $U\oplus W$ gives back the two projections onto the two summands.
There are exactly $n+1$ conjugacy classes of projections, which are determined by the rank of the projection. And it is not too difficult to calculate out the size of such a given conjugacy class using the orbit-stabilizer-formula: Suppose $P$ is a projection of rank $r\leq n$. As $P$ is similar to the block matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ (where the various $0$'s stand for zero matrices of appropriate sizes), we may well assume $P$ to be of this exact form. By orbit-stabilizer, the conjugacy class of $P$ is then of size $\frac{|\mathrm{GL}(V)|}{|\mathrm{Stab}(P)|}$,
where $\mathrm{Stab}(P)$ in this case is just the centralizer of $P$ in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, i.e. the subgroup of invertible matrices $X$ that satisfy $XP=PX$. To determine this subgroup, we write $X=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C& D \end{pmatrix}$ (with $A$ of size $r\times r$ and so forth) and calculate
$$XP-PX=...=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -B \\ C &0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence, $X$ commutes with $P$ if and only if both $B$ and $C$ are $0$. In this case, $X$ is invertible if and only if both $A$ and $D$ are. As such, we find that
$$\mathrm{Stab}(P)=\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathbb{F}_2)\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-r}(\mathbb{F}_2).$$
If you now plug in the general formula $|\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathbb{F}_2)|=\prod_{i=0}^{r-1}(2^r-2^i),$
you can use this to calculate the size of the conjugacy class of all projections of rank $r$. Summing these totals over all $n+1$ possible ranks and dividing out by $2$ then gives the final count.

I notice this https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_subgroup_is_a_direct_factor_iff_direct_product_of_elementary_Abelian_groups  According to this conclusion, we just need to determine the total number of subgroup, right? This one seems to have knows consequences.

Not quite, any given subgroup will typically have many different complementary subgroups and will therefore feature in many direct sum decompositions.
